# Contractibility of a poset-indexed colimit

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, limits-and-colimits

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a poset with distinguished element $p$, and let $P'$ be the poset of "finite chains which weakly descend to $p$" given by all $\sigma = (x_0 \geq x_1 \geq \cdots \geq x_k \geq p)$ ordered by inclusion. Let $d_i\sigma$ denote that element of $P'$ which is obtained by omitting $x_i$ and note that $P'$ has minimal element consisting of the singleton chain $p$.

For each $\sigma \in P'$ as written above, I have a product
$$K_\sigma = K_{0,1} \times K_{1,2} \times \cdots \times K_{k-1,k} \times K_p$$
where each $K_{\bullet,\bullet}$ in sight is a contractible simplicial complex, as is the distinguished complex $K_p$.

I'm dealing with a typical colimit construction given (as usual) by a disjoint union over all $\sigma \in P'$

$$ C = \coprod_{\sigma} K_\sigma {\huge /} \sim,$$

where $\sim$ is a collection of equivalence relations $\sim_i$ which identify a contractible subcomplex of $K_\sigma$ with a contractible subcomplex of $K_{d_i\sigma}$. And with that out of the way, here is the question.

> What is the most general Theorem which shows that $C$ is contractible? In particular, I'd like to relax any assumptions about the finiteness of $X$ and the $K_{\bullet,\bullet}$ if possible, so the usual argument by induction no longer seems satisfactory.

When $X$ is finite, I can inductively show that $C$ contracts to $K_p$, but I'd like a general argument, preferably via Quillen's theorem A or some such slick method.